# text partially saved on mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

I have a strange problem (at least for me). I have a form with a textarea (using ckeditor but tried also others..) and when i submit a text, it is partially saved on my database.

Database is utf8mb4_unicode_ci and the column where i store data is a text datatype with uf8mb4 collation.

Using phpmyadmin if i put pure text (no html inside) inside the column it is stored without problems. If i put text using the form it only stores a part of the text. It seems like html tag are not allowed..

The page has:

```
meta charset='UTF-8'
```

When i connect to the database i use this string:

```
if(!mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8mb4")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
```

this is the code i use to store data inside the database:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/",'',$_POST['id']);                         // ID AUTOVETTURA

$testo = $_POST['testo'];                                               // PRENDO TESTO

$tabella = $_POST['tabella'];                                           // LEGGO TABELLA DOVE: 1 = CHI SIAMO; 2 = DISCLAIMER; 3 = PRIVACY; 4 = COOKIE; 5 = CONDIZIONIVENDITA;

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);                                         // INIZIALIZZO LA CONNESSIONE


if($tabella == 1){
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'UPDATE chisiamo
                                SET chisiamo.testo = ?
                                WHERE chisiamo.id = ?')
                                or die(mysqli_error($con));             // QUERY RECUPERO DATI

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'si',$testo,$id);                      // PREPARO I PARAMETRI

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                                         // ESEGUO LA QUERY
}

if($tabella == 2){
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'UPDATE disclaimer
                                SET disclaimer.testo = ?
                                WHERE disclaimer.id = ?')
                                or die(mysqli_error($con));             // QUERY RECUPERO DATI

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'si',$testo,$id);                      // PREPARO I PARAMETRI

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                                         // ESEGUO LA QUERY
}

if($tabella == 3){
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'UPDATE privacy
                                SET privacy.testo = ?
                                WHERE privacy.id = ?')
                                or die(mysqli_error($con));             // QUERY RECUPERO DATI

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'si',$testo,$id);                      // PREPARO I PARAMETRI

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                                         // ESEGUO LA QUERY
}

if($tabella == 4){
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'UPDATE cookie
                                SET cookie.testo = ?
                                WHERE cookie.id = ?')
                                or die(mysqli_error($con));             // QUERY RECUPERO DATI

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'si',$testo,$id);                      // PREPARO I PARAMETRI

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                                         // ESEGUO LA QUERY
}

if($tabella == 5){
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'UPDATE condizionivendita
                                SET condizionivendita.testo = ?
                                WHERE condizionivendita.id = ?')
                                or die(mysqli_error($con));             // QUERY RECUPERO DATI

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'si',$testo,$id);                      // PREPARO I PARAMETRI

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                                         // ESEGUO LA QUERY
}

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                                             // ESEGUO LA QUERY

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);                                               // CHIUDO LO STATEMENT
mysqli_close($con);                                                     // CHIUDO CONNESSIONE   

?>
```

that's the connection code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

if (!$con) {
    die('Connection Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if(!mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8mb4")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
```

i also  tried to use addslashes function on text before the query but it doesn't solved my problem..

Any hint please?

Edit:

This is the function i use to call the php script to record data into database:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var id = 1;
    var testo = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData()

    alert(testo);
    var tabella = $('#tabella').val();
    var data_1 = 'testo=' + testo + '&id=' + id + '&tabella=' + tabella;    
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      data: data_1,
      url: "php/aggiorna_pagine.php"
    })
    .done(function(){
      $('.success').show();
      $('.success').fadeOut(2000);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: ok i edited the question, thanks

Comment: can you provide a piece of text that does not save properly.

Comment: Articolo 1 - Oggetto
Le presenti Condizioni Generali hanno per oggetto un salvataggio a utomatico e se c'è un apostrofo

ok when there is an apostrophe the text is truncated.. so i tried also with

this line of code but nothing changed:

$testo2 = addslashes($testo);

Comment: Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` for every userinput you save in a database. Otherwise your database is vulnerable for SQL Injections.

Comment: @FrankM hes using bound parameters. a million times better than `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @rtfm what does it mean :"hes using bound paramaters" ? i do not understand everything in english..

Comment: What character set are you using for the html page itself? Is the text truncated before the SQL statement?

Comment: @P.Davide: He means that the code uses a parameterized query with bound variables (parameters) so he doesn't need to escape the strings, mysqli will do that.

Comment: in the html page i have this: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

Comment: @P.Davide your using `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` which does the escaping. and is much better than `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you used `mysqli_real_escape_string` they would be escaped twice making a real messs

Comment: #rtfm yes, thanks for explanation. I see now that i have page language set as english but it is italian language that i used inside the page

Comment: My first thought is that you're writing to a varchar that's too small for the text you're trying to write.

Comment: Many of the editors will remove characters they don't understand or that are outside the character set they are setup for. I don't think it's in the PHP  or SQL. Try with a plain textbox.

Comment: i also change from thext to longtext to be sure that there is enough space inside column

Comment: so better try another text editor?

Comment: I doubt the column type is the issue unless your text entry is a great deal larger that you indicate. It's most likely an issue with the editor or page character set

Comment: For testing/debugging, try a plain text area

Comment: with a plain textarea when i copy the text that I need and paste it on the textarea i have no problems. it is copied as a plain text (with no html tag inside)

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['testo'])` at the start of your PHP page give you?

Comment: var_dump() where should i use it? when doing the query? at the very top of the file?